# Unable for forwardRef in React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-final-form, final-form

Using `react-final-form` i am unable to `forwardRef` to my `TextInput` for React Native. The `ref` is required for handling the `Next` button in keyboards and other forced-focus events in forms.

My setup is as follows - please note that some code has been removed for simplicity so this won't cut and paste.

```
// FormInputGroup/index.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Field } from 'react-final-form'

const FormInputGroup = ({ Component, validate, ...rest }) => (
  <Field component={Component} validate={validate} {...rest} />
)

FormInputGroup.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  Component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.object]),
  validate: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array, PropTypes.func]),
}

export default FormInputGroup
```

```
// Form/index.js

import { Form } from 'react-final-form'
import { FormInputGroup, FormInputText, ButtonPrimary } from '/somewhere/'
...

const passwordInputRef = useRef()

<Form
  onSubmit={({ email, password }) => {
    // submit..
  }}
>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <>
      <FormInputGroup
        name="email"
        Component={FormInputText}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => passwordInputRef.current.focus()}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
      />
      <FormInputGroup
        name="password"
        Component={FormInputText}
        returnKeyType="go"
        onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
        ref={passwordInputRef} // <-- This does not work which i think is to be expected...
      />
      <ButtonPrimary loading={loading} onPress={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </ButtonPrimary>
    </>
  )}
</Form>

...
```

```
// FormInputText/index.js

const FormInputText = forwardRef( // <-- added forwardRef to wrap the component
  (
    {
      input,
      meta: { touched, error },
      label,
      ...
      ...rest
    },
    ref,
  ) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        {label ? (
          <Text bold style={styles.label}>
            {label}
          </Text>
        ) : null}
        <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={input.onChange}
            value={input.value}
            ...
            ref={ref}
            {...rest}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  },
)
```

I think the code falls down with the `<FormInputGroup />` component. A clue to this is if i change the rendering on the form to be as follows;

```
...

     <FormInputGroup
        name="password"
        Component={props => <FormInputText {...props} ref={passwordInputRef} />} // <-- changed
        returnKeyType="go"
        onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
      />

...
```

This does seem to forward the ref, but "breaks" `final-form` with each keystroke dismissing the keyboard, presumably due to a re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't forward the ref from `FormInputGroup`.

You need to capture the ref at the level it is passed down and further forward it to the children. This is how it should be:

```
const FormInputGroup = forwardRef(({ Component, validate, ...rest }, ref) => (
  <Field ref={ref} component={Component} validate={validate} {...rest} />
))
```

Comment: You're absolutely right... i don't know how i missed this solution as i had thought the same thinking. I suppose in my variations, i had not quite nailed it properly! 

The `FormInputGroup` was the missing link as you described. Everything else seemed to be in the right place :)